# Selecting a subset of properties from nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, iteration, jq

I have a deeply nested array of objects I am trying to pull a subset of key and values from.

```
[
    {
        "x": {
          "y": {
            "description": "jq rocks",
            "z": [
              {
                "data_1": 123,
                "data_2": [
                  {
                    "field_1": true,
                    "field_2": "hello",
                    "field_3": "red"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "data_1": 123,
                "data_2": [
                  {
                    "field_1": true,
                    "field_2": "goodbye",
                    "field_3": "blue"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "data_1": 123
              }
            ]
          }
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to extract field_2 and field_3, plus some other fields but the issue I'm running into is it seems to be combining every possible combination of field_2 and field_3.

The jq I'm currently using is

```
jq '.[] | {
  "description": .x.y.description,
  "subset": [{
     "f_2": .x.y.z[].data_2[]?.field_2,
     "f_3": .x.y.z[].data_2[]?.field_3
  }]
}' tmp.json
```

When using the example above it returns 4 entries in the array instead of just two.

```
"subset": [
  {
    "f_2": "hello"
    "f_3": "red"
  }
  {
    "f_2": "hello"
    "f_3": "blue"
  }
  {
    "f_2": "goodbye"
    "f_3": "red"
  }
  {
    "f_2": "goodbye"
    "f_3": "blue"
  }
]
```

How do I force jq to process each object in the data_2 array once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
.[].x.y | { description, subset: [.z[].data_2[]? | { f_2: .field_2, f_3: .field_3 }] }
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/b-HCJL7MTa).

Your problem stems from defining two fields based on two iterations in the same object. `[{foo: .x.y.z[].data_2[]?.field_2}]` returns two items, but `[{foo: .x.y.z[].data_2[]?.field_2, bar: .x.y.z[].data_2[]?.field_3}]` returns 4. Factorizing the iteration solves the problem.